# java printing index cards

Tags: java, printing

I 'm developing this Java app and I'm trying to print
individual captioned storyboards on index cards, i.e. one image per card.

I had envisaged that I might be able to do this by printing in landscape mode
on a standard 4" x 6" index card but my printer, which is a fairly new
HP Photosmart 5515 just can't cope with it.

The cards can only be loaded into the printer lengthways, otherwise it says the
stationary is too short. When you select portrait mode it prints okay, but it's
kind of counter-intuitive and it's wasting space above and below the
storyboard image, which then only occupies a third of the available space.

When you tell the machine to print in landscape mode it STILL prints in portrait mode,
but with completely ridiculous margin settings.

```
protected void setPageFormat(PrinterJob job) {

    PageFormat defaultPageFormat = job.defaultPage();
    Paper paper = defaultPageFormat.getPaper();
    paper.setImageableArea(0.0D, 0.0D, paper.getWidth(), paper.getHeight());


    defaultPageFormat.setPaper(paper);

    // sets imageable size to maximum allowable margins
    pageFormat = job.validatePage(defaultPageFormat);
}
```

I use the PrinterJob method **validatePage** to ensure that the margins are ok, and it is
this routine that is returning the tiny margin settings.

When I use A4 paper instead
of index cards, the margins are perfectly okay. When I select landscape index card
and look at the pageFormat object, it tells me it's portrait, even though I selected
landscape, and even though the width is given as longer than the height.

Any suggestions, gratefully appreciated